# Error in JDK installation in ubuntu docker

Tags: java, docker, java-8, ubuntu-18.04

I have a docker file like below.

```
FROM ubuntu
FROM python:3.6

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install wget curl software-properties-common -y
RUN apt-get install g++ gcc mercurial -y


RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y ant && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer;

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME
```

When i try to build the docker using  ***sudo docker build -t test_dock .*** command, there is an error saying

> Unable to locate jdk package

So i have added

```
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
```

before jdk installation command.
Now the build errors out saying

> E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal
>   Release' does not have a Release file.

What is the correct way to install jdk in ubuntu docker?

Comment: I'd start from the Docker Hub [openjdk](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk) image, not `python`.  (Your `FROM ubuntu` line does nothing in this Dockerfile.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I was curious and sure enough the `FROM ubuntu` doesn't even cause `docker` to `pull` the image if it doesn't already exist locally. Cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me solved by replacing :

```
FROM ubuntu
FROM python:3.6
```

To:

```
FROM python:3-stretch
```